# Does this inequality hold?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification, economics

I am currently writting a paper and ended up with an expression that looks like the following:

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}C_{i}}{\sum_{i=1} {N_i}^\gamma {C_{i}}^{1-\gamma}}$$

for $i=1...K$, $C_i>0$, $N_i \in [0,1]$ such that $\sum_iN_i=1$, and $\gamma \in [0,1]$I want to know if the following inequality holds:

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}C_{i}}{\sum_{i=1} {N_i}^\gamma {C_{i}}^{1-\gamma}}\leq \frac{K\max_kC_{k}}{\sum_{i=1} {N_i}^\gamma \max_k\{{C_{k}}\}^{1-\gamma}} $$ 
$$=\frac{\max_k \{C_k\} K}{\max_k \{C_k\}^{1-\gamma}\sum_{i=1} {N_i}^\gamma}$$
$$=\frac{\max_k \{C_k\}^\gamma K}{\sum_{i=1} {N_i}^\gamma}$$

Note that I am basically trying to apply max inside both sums. My intuition is that this inequality holds. However, I haven´t been able to prove it, so now I have my doubts. What do you think?

Comment: Does it help if you rewrite your first expression as

$$\displaystyle\sum_i \frac{C_i}{N_i^{\gamma}C_i^{1-\gamma}}$$

?

Comment: Just added a middle step to clarify how I get to the last expression. I think you can´t rewrite the fraction as you suggest though.

Comment: Are each of the $C_i>0$? I usually think of trying maximize a ratio of positive quantities by (1) maximizing the numerator, and (2) *minimizing* the denominator (not *maximizing* the denominator). The idea is that the fraction is larger if the denominator shrinks. That may not be your approach here, though--just throwing that in.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: you seem to be claiming that $$1=\frac{2+2}{2+2}=\frac22+\frac22=2.$$

Comment: @MartinArgerami Wow I'm an idiot

Comment: @MPW I usually try to use your approach. However, in this case being able to apply the $\max$ to both numerator and denominator would be very useful. My expectation is that somewhat the weights and the $\gamma$ will make the effect in the numerator to dominate.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: No, but take it as a learning experience  that one has to be careful with formalism and never forget what you are trying to represent with it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality is false. Take $K=2$, $\gamma=1/2$ and
$$
C_1=100,\quad C_2=1,\quad N_1=1,\quad N_2=100.
$$
Then
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}C_{i}}{\sum_{i=1} {N_i}^\gamma {C_{i}}^{1-\gamma}}=\frac{101}{20}>5
$$
and
$$
\frac{K\max_iC_{i}}{\sum_{i=1} {N_i}^\gamma \max_k\{{C_{k}}\}^{1-\gamma}}=\frac{200}{10\cdot(10+1)}<2
$$

PS. A commentator correctly remarked that the hypothesis was $N_i\in[0,1]$ and $N_1+N_2=1$, so the example must be rescaled (both members are $\gamma$-homogeneous in $N_i$). I  leave the example as it is, because it is easier to evaluate the square roots.
However the idea is simple: you have problems when in the sum $\sum_i N_i^\gamma C_i^{1-\gamma}$ very small $N_i$ meet the big $C_i$ and viceversa.

Comment: But the requirement is that $N_2\in[0,1]$. You can probably scale the example, though.